# Microsoft EDGE reports XHR HTTP404 with typescript file

Tags: asp.net, debugging, typescript, visual-studio-2015, microsoft-edge

When I debug a Typescript web-application from Visual Studio 2015, using the Microsoft EDGE browser it reports the following;

```
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR): GET - http://localhost:2543/scripts/Helpers/jsontable.ts
```

I have a `jsontable.ts` file in my project, but it is NOT located under `scripts`.
I have also done a full text-search in my solution, and haven't found other references to 'jsontable.ts' other than in the `_references.ts` file which I have now removed. The problem is still there.
Other browsers doesn't report this error in the F12 network-pane (tested with Internet Explorer 11, Chrome, Opera and FireFox). I know for sure I don't send this request myself from other states in my application.
Has anyone else experienced this. Is there any fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably sourceMaps. Turn off that option in your `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: I didn't have a tsconfig.json file, but your answer made my change the root directory of source maps in TypeScript Build project-properties. Somehow the XHR error disappeared, so I'll mark this as an answer. Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with VS2015 but I know this issue has to do with sourceMaps. There's no other reason for a browser to request source files. 